# Fill shapes/contours using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

i would like to fill in part of numpy matrix that satisfies certain properties (using mask possibly). Namely, it is a matrix representation of some shape, for example, square would be:

```
square =   [0,0,0,0,0;
            0,1,1,1,0;
            0,1,0,1,0;
            0,1,1,1,0]
```

becomes:

```
s_filled = [0,0,0,0,0;
            0,1,1,1,0;
            0,1,1,1,0;
            0,1,1,1,0]
```

and circle:

```
circle =   [0,0,0,0,0,0;
            0,0,1,1,0,0;
            0,1,0,0,1,0;
            0,0,1,1,0,0]
```

and becomes:

```
c_filled = [0,0,0,0,0,0;
            0,0,1,1,0,0;
            0,1,1,1,1,0;
            0,0,1,1,0,0]
```

Is this possible with using numpy only and no other external libraries?
I would like to apply this function/algorithm to 300x300 shapes.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but No sorry. I need more general solution. This will only work if you need to fill in your inner shape with 1s while outer part is all 0s (not the other way around).

Answer (score 5):

Pretty simple with [`np.maximum.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html), as we could use it once along the rows from left to right and then from right to left and simply get the common area of non-zeros by subtraction. This would work nicely for convex shapes.

Thus, an implementation would be -

```
def fill_contours(arr):
    return np.maximum.accumulate(arr,1) & \
           np.maximum.accumulate(arr[:,::-1],1)[:,::-1]
```

Here's a sample run on an arbitrary shape -

```
In [176]: arbitrary
Out[176]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

In [177]: fill_contours(arbitrary)
Out[177]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: This solution worked very well for me when filling in a circle object. Seems universal in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little fix for @Divakar 's answer to fix concave filling in some edge cases.

The original solution can't solve this case because it doesn't skip the elements that are on the vertical axis.

For example:

```
# check out index (7, 2), the result should be 0.0

a = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

fill_contours(a)
"""
original_result
 0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 
 0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0 
 0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0 
 0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0 
 0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0 
 0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0 
 0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 
"""

# not apply the fix by considering vertical axis
def fill_contours_fixed(arr):
    return np.maximum.accumulate(arr, 1) &\
           np.maximum.accumulate(arr[:, ::-1], 1)[:, ::-1] &\
           np.maximum.accumulate(arr[::-1, :], 0)[::-1, :] &\
           np.maximum.accumulate(arr, 0)

fill_contours_fixed(a)

"""
fixed_result, (7, 2) is now correct
 0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 
 0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0 
 0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0 
 0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0 
 0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0 
 0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0 
 0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
"""
```